# javascript how to get the web page get Session variable

Tags: javascript, session

I'm trying to use a Session variable in javascript.

I have tried a  number of post suggestions without success unfortinately.

I see this example all over the place.

```
    var userName = '<%= Session["UserName"] %>'
```

However that is not working, at least for me. What I am trying to do is as below.

```
    var qrdataString = "<qr-code data=" + "XL" + ' <%= Session["style"] %>'  + "></qr-code>";
    document.getElementById("styleqr").innerHTML = qrdataString;
```

Using Single quotes where they appear above just returns the string as

```
    <%=Session["xUID"]%>   in the alert that I use to show me the returned value
```

Using Double quotes give me either - unexpected token: string literal - or unexpected token identifier.

Thanks

Comment: is this plain client-side javascript or server-side jsp?

Comment: plain client-side, thanks

Comment: its not me who downvoted, but maybe because you're using ```<%=``` without tagging asp.net/jsp/ruby (or any server-side scripting you're using) ? ```<%=Session["xUID"]%>``` is clearly not a client-side code to me

Comment: Thanks @Kristian Perhaps my mistake. It is ASP.Net so I guess it could be considered server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around for a while, and also stumbling on the following article, I have managed to get this going.

```
    https://newbedev.com/get-current-session-value-in-javascript
```

FULL RESULT

HTML

```
    Dim xstyle: xstyle = session("style")

    <div class="hr">
      <input type="hidden" id="hdnSession" data-value= <%= xstyle %> />
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    var hdnString= $("#hdnSession").data('value');
    var qrdataString = "<qr-code data= " + hdnString  + " ></qr-code>";
    document.getElementById("qrcode").innerHTML = qrdataString;
```

HTML

```
    <div class="panel-body" id="qrcode">
        javasctipt inserts the html here  <!--qr-code data="test"></qr-code -->
    </div>
```